# cocos creator can not build for android platform

Tags: python, android

The information I got as follows.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\CocosCreator\resources\cocos2d-x\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\cocos.py", line 983, in 
      run_plugin(command, argv, plugins)
  File "C:\CocosCreator\resources\cocos2d-x\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\cocos.py", line 875, in run_plugin
    plugin.run(argv, dependencies_objects)
  File "C:\CocosCreator\resources\cocos2d-x\tools\cocos2d-console\plugins\plugin_new\project_new.py", line 258, in run
    self.parse_args(argv)
  File "C:\CocosCreator\resources\cocos2d-x\tools\cocos2d-console\plugins\plugin_new\project_new.py", line 104, in parse_args
    description=self.__class__.brief_description())
  File "C:\CocosCreator\resources\cocos2d-x\tools\cocos2d-console\plugins\plugin_new\project_new.py", line 43, in brief_description
    return MultiLanguage.get_string('NEW_BRIEF')
  File "C:\CocosCreator\resources\cocos2d-x\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\MultiLanguage.py", line 52, in get_string
    fmt = cls.get_instance().get_current_string(key)
  File "C:\CocosCreator\resources\cocos2d-x\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\MultiLanguage.py", line 158, in get_current_string
    ret = ret.encode(self.encoding)
  File "C:\CocosCreator\resources\utils\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-8: character maps to <undefined>
```

any one knows why this happened?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know python, but the problem seems solved afterI made the modification to the line 158 of MultiLanguage.py(in the get_current_string method):

```
ret = ret.encode(self.encoding)
```

to the following line:

```
        ret = ret.encode("utf8") #self.encoding
```

Hope this helps people who encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the versions of NDK and SDK, NDK. The recommended version is R17 - R19